# In Angular 2, how can we Decorate a class and maintain dependency injection of the original constructor?

Tags: angular

So I am trying to decorate a class and it's working fine except that I am losing my original class's constructor dependency injection and so of course everything is failing.

So my original class is:

```
@RefreshTheme
export class App implements AfterContentInit {
private m_commBroker:CommBroker;
private m_styleService:StyleService;

constructor(commBroker:CommBroker, styleService:StyleService) {
    this.m_styleService = styleService;
    this.m_commBroker = commBroker;
    ...
```

so as you can see I am DI commBroker and styleService

and my @RefreshTheme is:

```
export function RefreshTheme<TFunction extends Function>(Target: TFunction): TFunction {
var newConstructor = function () {
    Target.apply(this);
    Object.freeze(this);
};

newConstructor.prototype = Object.create(Target.prototype);
newConstructor.prototype.constructor = Target;

return <any> newConstructor;
```

}

and as long as I don't use DI in the original class, all is good... but I need to respect the original class constructor regardless of what it is (diff classes will of course have diff constructor signatures).

Thanks for reading,

Regards

Sean.

Comment: Actually I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "I am losing my original class's constructor dependency injection"

Comment: well if I use the above code, my original constructor will NOT receive the dependency injection of commBroker:CommBroker, styleService:StyleService

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are invoking the App constructor without passing in the required parameters. DI will have to be initiated from the top since that is a fundamental principle of DI.

The same applies if you were simply extending the class

```
MyApp extends App{
  constructor(commBroker:CommBroker){
    super(commBroker)
  }
}
```

If it didn't work this way you would negate a lot of the benefits of DI since you would be delegating dependency control to a different component (in this case the base)

Comment: well that's exactly what I am struggling with, how do I pass the given args (in this case DI vars) so when decorating the class (constructor) I can keep the same original dependencies from the calling original class... not possible from what I can tell... hopefully I am wrong...